# Flair section link can be updated in the flair help page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, help-center, flair

In the end of the current [What is Flair?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/flair) help page, there is a link to the profile settings page as `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current`. Which is pointing to edit profile page then we need to select the Flair section to see the details.

Since we have a direct link to navigate to the Flair section as `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair`.

So shall we update the direct link to Flair section in the help page?

Current content in the flair help page as:

> For more information, log in and visit the Flair section of [your profile's Site Settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current).

Expected content which is something similar to this or better than this:

> For more information, log in and visit to [Flair section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair) on your profile's settings page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've now edited the `/help/flair` Help Center page network-wide. In addition to updating the link, I did some copyediting and clarified some phrasing as well. [The page](/help/flair) now reads:

> Flair is an image summarizing your accomplishments on $SiteName or the Stack Exchange network (your reputation, your badges, the top sites you've participated on), suitable for display on your own website – or printing out and pinning to a vest, if that's what you prefer.
>
> #### Example:
>
> [image]
>
> To see what your flair looks like and how to use it, log in and go to the "[Flair](/users/flair)" page on the Settings tab of your profile.